# Android MultiThread game

Tags: android, multithreading, opengl-es

I am working on a simple android game. I came to a point that I would like to optimize my engine with multithreading. I am working in OpenGL ES, Android 2.2

Now UpdateGame() and RenderScene() run in single thread and are executed in onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)

I have a RenderObject class that has Position, Rotation, Scale, and Color members. All RenderObjects are created when I start my game and are stored in RenderObject array.

In UpdateGame() function I go through RenderObjects in RenderObject array and update new Position, Rotation, Scale and Color.

In RenderScene() function I go through RenderObjects in RenderObject array and render them with new Position, Rotation, Scale and Color.

This works ok in single thread.

So then I tried create a thread for UpdateGame().

So my idea is to:

Update Thread:................Render Thread:

Update Frame 0

Update Frame 1................Render Frame 0....Update and Render work in parallel

Update Frame 2................Render Frame 1

Update Frame 3................Render Frame 2

But first I modified RenderObject class so that it has RenderPosition, RenderRotation, RenderScale and RenderColor members.

These members get copied just before rendering previous frame. So that parallel update thread can modify new Position, Rotation, Scale, Color.

```
Runnable pRunnable;
Thread pThread;
public int renderframe = 0;
piblic int updateframe = 0;

public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) 
{
    // I create a new thread in this function        
    pRunnable = new Runnable(){
         public void run(){
             while(true)
             {
                 while( renderframe < updateframe )
                 {
                     // WAITING for render to finish so that data does not get corrupterd
                 }
                 // 
                 // I update RenderObject Position, Rotation, Scale, Color members here
                 UpdateGame();
                 updateframe++;
             }  
         }
    };

    pThread = new Thread(pRunnable);
    pThread.start();
}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) 
{
    while( renderframe == updateframe )
    {
         // Wait for update to finish
    }

    for(int a=0;a<MAX_RENDER_OBJECTS;a++)
    {
        RenderObject ro = aRenderObjects[a];
        // I do this in a function
        ro.RenderPosition[0] = ro.Position[0];
        ro.RenderPosition[1] = ro.Position[1];
        ro.RenderPosition[2] = ro.Position[2];
        ro.RenderPosition[3] = ro.Position[3];
        // I do the same for Rotation, Scale, Color

    }

    renderframe++;

    // When rendering scene I use RenderPosition, RenderRotation members when calling OpenGL API
    RenderScene(); 

}
```

But when I run my game. The graphics are incorrect. It appears as if data is not in sync.

Any suggestion there on how to appropriately sync RenderObject data between Update and Render threads.

Thank you.

Comment: Try this question over at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

This style seems generally inefficient (spin-waiting loops that will block the two threads from working simultaneously) and dangerous (I don't know how Android implements this, but Java memory model does not guarantee that data from one thread is visible to another thread without going through a synchronized block).

My suggestion is this: the main thread is the rendering thread (GL contexts are thread-local, so you can't use it from another thread (though you can create another context on another thread to perform some data sharing)), and spawns the update thread. The main thread then goes on a loop, waiting on a mutex on every iteration. The update thread updates the game logic, and creates a new object representing everything that has to be drawn (e.g. a list of drawing commands). This object is then put on a queue and the main thread is woken (with notify()). The main thread then gets the drawing data and draws it.

You'll probably want to dismiss older sets of data in case the update loop is much faster than the render loop, but this general idea should get you started.

Comment: In Android the GL context is on its own thread, the main thread is reserved to handle Android events. I would follow your approach with a drawing queue and notify, but launch the game state thread from the Activity, not the Renderer. User input will also need to be passed from the Activity to the game update thread in a similar fashion.